# Highlighting Specific Proportion of Data Layer using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, analysis

[image]

I am trying to highlight an arbitrary percentage of a coral reef vector layer. I am **trying to see what 30% of this layer looks like**, but I cannot figure out how to do this. I tried customizing the extent of the layer, but it wouldn't let me. I even tried to see if I can perform a negative buffer on this with no luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello @summer, can you simplify what do you mean by 30%? Is it based on feature count, area, or just display?

Comment: Create a fishnet grid of squares, for example 100*100 m squares (or something, I dont know the size of your reef layer), select squares until you reach 30 % of total area, Copy to a new layer.

Comment: @YogeshChavan Hi! It's just a visual thing that is also based on my area. The purpose of it is to see what 30% of this area looks like. I pasted a picture in my original post so you can see the layer.

Comment: If you have an area field you could just select a bunch of records by the usual windows selection methods and use the the right button calculate statistics, then select more or less until you approximate 30% of the total and look at the selection in your map.  If the selections clump more than you like sort by different fields to get a "random" like feel to the table order before selecting.  Inelegant but it works for a rough look.

Comment: @BERA Great! I just matched up the fishnet to the extent of the layer so it overlays it. Now, is there a way to manually break it down or select the individual grid squares?

Comment: @johns Thanks so much! I actually just did something similar. I calculated the area by .30 using the field calculator. It's a random 30% but it works! Thanks for the help:)

Comment: Just [select them](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/selecting-features-interactively.htm) manually